How to load an image in Kotlin Multiplatform for Desktop?
I'd like to set a background image to my Compose Desktop app. The image is a local file included in the project.
I can see there are several overloads of Image constructor:

Image(bitmap, ..)
Image(imageVector, ..)
Image(painter, ..)

My image is a bitmap, but I'm not sure how to convert from a file to ImageBitmap in Kotlin Multiplatform for Desktop.

I figured there are two options in my case:
Use ImageBitmap

Load the image file (relative to project root) as bytes
Use org.jetbrains.skia.Image to decode the bytes into an image
Call .toComposeImageBitmap() to convert that to a Bitmap that can be used in Image(bitmap)

fun loadImageFrom(filePath: String): ImageBitmap {
    val bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(filePath)) // path relative to project root
    return Image.makeFromEncoded(bytes).toComposeImageBitmap()
}

val file = loadImageFrom("src/main/assets/background.jpg")
Image(bitmap = file, contentDescription = null)

Use Painter

Put the image in the resource folder
Use the androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource() function to load the image directly from the resource folder

Image(painter = painterResource("background.jpg"), contentDescription = null)

The resource folder must be placed in a source set (e.g. src/main) and must be called resources!
Full path would be: src/main/resources/background.jpg
I previously called the folder assets which didn't work even when I marked it as a resource root.. This seems to be some pre-configured convention and I couldn't find where it's defined.
